# How to combine two table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, merge

I have two table(tbl_CUST, tbl_Total)

**tbl_CUST**

```
Name   Sex  ProductName   Price
Jonh   M    iPhone 6s     $ 1200
Smith  M    iPhone 6      $ 900
Mary   F    Samsung S7    $ 800
```

**tbl_total** (Have only one record)

```
Total   Date             
$2,900   20-05-2016

This the result that I did. But I don't need like that:
            Name   Sex  ProductName   Price    Total    Date
            Jonh   M    iPhone 6s     $ 1,200   $2,900  20-05-2016
            Smith  M    iPhone 6      $ 900
            Mary   F    Samsung S7    $ 800

 Now I need to combine table and show the result like that: 
            Name   Sex  ProductName   Price    Total    Date
            Jonh   M    iPhone 6s     $ 1,200   $2,900  20-05-2016
            Smith  M    iPhone 6      $ 900
            Mary   F    Samsung S7    $ 800

 So, What's can I do? Please help me! Thanks so much!
```

Comment: Your two output tables look identical to me.  What do you want to do here?

Comment: My Question is wrong. What's I need at the Columns Total and Date I need to show only one record.

Answer (score 0):

$sql=mysql_query("select * from `tbl_CUST` inner join  `tbl_Total` on `tbl_Total`.`Name`=`tbl_CUST`.`Name`",$conn);

Use inner join in query for tow table merge. Here in this "NAME" is condition for both table, where query return only same name records only other record is hide.